A connected, locally compact metric space is $\sigma$-compact
On p.5 of Spivak's first book on differential geometry he proves that if $X$ is a connected and locally compact metric space, then it is $\sigma$-compact and there are a few things in the proof that i don't quite get. He first define for each $x\in X$ the number $r(x)$ as one-half the least upper bound of all $r>0$ such that the ball $B(x,r)$ of center $x$ and radius $r$ is compact (assuming that there is not an $x_0\in X$ such that the set of all those $r>0$ is all the positive real numbers, since in that case $X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B(x_0,n)$). Then he proves that $|r(x_1)-r(x_2)|\leq \frac{1}{2}d(x_1,x_2)$ and so $r:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Then he takes a compact set $A\subset X$ and defines $$A'=\bigcup_{y\in A}B(y,r(y))$$ and if we have a sequence $(z_n)$ in $A'$ of course we have that for each $i$ there is a $y_i\in A$ such that $z_i\in B(y_i,r(y_i))$. Now here is the part that i don't understand: since $A$ is compact, some subsequence of $y_i$ which we might assume that is the sequence itself, converses to some $y\in A$. Then the ball $B\left(y,\frac{3}{2}r(y)\right)$ is compact.
Why we can assume that we can take the sequence $(y_i)$ itself such that it converges? And  why is the ball $B\left(y,\frac{3}{2}r(y)\right)$ compact? Also i don't fully get the rest of the proof, so if someone could give this proof in more detail I would appreciate it.

Spivak writes (I quote):

For each $x\in X$ consider those numbers $r>0$ such that the closed
ball $\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)\leq r\}$ is a compact set (...) define $r(x)$ to be
one half the least upper bound of such $r$.

This answers your second question since $\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}<1$, it follows that $B(y,3r(y)/2)$ is compact.
W.r.t. the first question, a subsequence of $y_i$ amounts, essentially, to neglecting some terms. He does not want to bother using another index such as $y_{i_k}$ so what he does is a slight abuse of notation and call $y_i$ the subsequence. This does not affect the proof (he wants a convergent subsequence of some $z_i$, and he will precisely picks the terms from the subsequence of $y_i$).
